# SecurityException on LG when trying to get external storage ringtone title

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I've used Android example and I have settings page with `RingtonePreference`.
In the example it binds the preference to a listener which on preference change sets the summary to reflect the user choice.
Recently an LG G2 user reported a crash on his device.
What happened is the default ringtone resides in external storage, which caused a SecurityException while `getTitle()` was called:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/60 from pid=20754, uid=10127 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

The whole backtrace:

```
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:485)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:429)
at com.lge.media.RingtoneManagerEx.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(RingtoneManagerEx.java:244)
at android.media.RingtoneEx.getTitle(RingtoneEx.java:177)
at android.media.RingtoneEx.getTitle(RingtoneEx.java:145)
at com.package.name.SettingsActivity$1.onPreferenceChange(SettingsActivity.java:77)
at com.package.name.SettingsActivity.bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(SettingsActivity.java:115)
at com.package.name.SettingsActivity.access$000(SettingsActivity.java:38)
at com.package.name.SettingsActivity$NotificationPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:235
```

Should I ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission ?
Is there another way? 
I've tried selecting a ringtone from external storage on my device (S7) and it worked perfectly, I didn't need any permission, why did it raise an exception on the LG device ?

Comment: Do you find any solution? I don't want to introduce one permission just for few LG devices.

Comment: Same here. Did you guys find something?

Comment: Since it's an internal small app, I had no problem adding the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I didn't find any other solution.